# How to delete all images from a PDF without corrupting it using CAM::PDF?

Tags: perl, pdf, cam-pdf

The script below is able to remove all images from a PDF file using `CAM::PDF`. The output, however, is corrupt. PDF readers are nonetheless able to open it, but they complain about errors. For instance, `mupdf` says:

```
error: no XObject subtype specified
error: cannot draw xobject/image
warning: Ignoring errors during rendering
mupdf: warning: Errors found on page
```

Now, `CAM::PDF` page at CPAN ([here](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/lib/CAM/PDF.pm)) lists the `deleteObject()` method under "Deeper utilities", presumably meaning that it's not intended for public usage. Moreover, it warns that:

> This function does NOT take care of dependencies on this object.

My question is: what is the right way to remove objects from a PDF file using `CAM::PDF`? If the issue has to do with dependencies, how can I remove an object while taking care of its dependencies?

For how to remove images from a PDF using other tools, see a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20676707/1839508).

```
use CAM::PDF;    
my $pdf = new CAM::PDF ( shift ) or die $CAM::PDF::errstr;

foreach my $objnum ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %{ $pdf->{xref} } ) {
  my $xobj = $pdf->dereference ( $objnum );

  if ( $xobj->{value}->{type} eq 'dictionary' ) {
    my $im = $xobj->{value}->{value};
    if
    (
      defined $im->{Type} and defined $im->{Subtype}
      and $pdf->getValue ( $im->{Type}    ) eq 'XObject'
      and $pdf->getValue ( $im->{Subtype} ) eq 'Image'
    )
    {
      $pdf->deleteObject ( $objnum );
    }
  }
}

$pdf->cleanoutput ( '-' );
```

Comment: Would you have a corrupt pdf that gives the mupdf errors available? I'm debugging a similar issue and it would be of great assistance :)

Answer (score 4):

This uses CAM::PDF, but takes a slightly different approach. Rather than attempting to delete the images, which is pretty hard, it replaces each image with a transparent image.

Firstly, note that we can use image magick to generate a blank PDF that contains nothing but a transparent image:

```
% convert  -size 200x100 xc:none transparent.pdf
```

If we view the generated PDF in a text editor, we can find the main image object:

```
8 0 obj
<<
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Name /Im0
...
```

The important thing to note here is that we have generated a transparent image as object number 8.

It then becomes matter of importing this object, and using it to replace each of the real images in the PDF, effectively blanking them.

```
use warnings; use strict;
use CAM::PDF;    
my $pdf = new CAM::PDF ( shift ) or die $CAM::PDF::errstr;

my $trans_pdf = CAM::PDF->new("transparent.pdf") || die "$CAM::PDF::errstr\n";
my $trans_objnum = 8; # object number of transparent image

foreach my $objnum ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %{ $pdf->{xref} } ) {
  my $xobj = $pdf->dereference ( $objnum );

  if ( $xobj->{value}->{type} eq 'dictionary' ) {
    my $im = $xobj->{value}->{value};
    if
    (
      defined $im->{Type} and defined $im->{Subtype}
      and $pdf->getValue ( $im->{Type}    ) eq 'XObject'
      and $pdf->getValue ( $im->{Subtype} ) eq 'Image'
    ) {
        $pdf->replaceObject ( $objnum, $trans_pdf, $trans_objnum, 1 );
    }
  }
}

$pdf->cleanoutput ( '-' );
```

The script now replaces each image in the PDF with the imported transparent image object(object number 8 from `transparent.pdf`).

Comment: Why 8? Where does it come from? We wouldn't be replacing object number 8 in the original document witht a transparent image, would we?

Comment: @.n.r. 8 is the object number of the image being imported from `transparent.pdf`. I've added more explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, which really deletes the images, is:

1. find and delete image XObjects in **resource lists**,
2. keep an array with **names** of deleted resources,
3. substitute **same-length** whitespace for the corresponding `Do` operators in each page content,
4. **clean up** and print.

Notice that dwarring's approach is safer, though, as it doesn't have to call `$doc->cleanse` at the end. According to the `CAM::PDF` documentation ([here](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/lib/CAM/PDF.pm)), the `cleanse` method

> Remove unused objects. WARNING: this function breaks some PDF documents because it removes objects that are strictly part of the page model hierarchy, but which are required anyway (like some font definition objects).

I don't know how much of a problem using `cleanse` can be.

```
use CAM::PDF;
my $doc = new CAM::PDF ( shift ) or die $CAM::PDF::errstr;

# delete image XObjects among resources
# but keep their names

my @names;

foreach my $objnum ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %{ $doc->{xref} } ) {
  my $obj = $doc->dereference( $objnum );
  next unless $obj->{value}->{type} eq 'dictionary';

  my $n = $obj->{value}->{value};

  my $resources = $doc->getValue ( $n->{Resources}       ) or next;
  my $resource  = $doc->getValue ( $resources->{XObject} ) or next;

  foreach my $name ( sort keys $resource ) {
    my $im = $doc->getValue ( $resource->{$name} ) or next;

    next unless defined $im->{Type}
            and defined $im->{Subtype}
            and $doc->getValue ( $im->{Type}    ) eq 'XObject'
            and $doc->getValue ( $im->{Subtype} ) eq 'Image';

    delete $resource->{$name};                                                                                                           
    push @names, $name;                                                                                                                  
  }                                                                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                                        


# delete the corresponding Do operators                                                                                                                        

if ( @names ) {                                                                                                                                                               
  foreach my $p ( 1 .. $doc->numPages ) {                                                                                                                                     
    my $content = $doc->getPageContent ( $p );
    my $s;
    foreach my $name ( @names ) {
      ++$s if $content =~ s{( / \Q$name\E \s+ Do \b )} { ' ' x length $1 }xeg;
    }
    $doc->setPageContent ( $p, $content ) if $s;
  }
}

$doc->cleanse;
$doc->cleanoutput;
```